# Download Excel Angular 8

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, loops, download

213/5000
I'm trying to download an excel file to Angular.
I have a "Day" column which should print from 1 to 31.
But if I do this, I only print the last number (31).

```
dataExcel : any;
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... , 31];

for(let i = 0 ; i <32; i++){
  this.dataExcel = [{
    Day: this.days[i]
  }]
}
```

How can I go about printing all the numbers in the excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not overwrite the existing array, you should keep adding new item (day) in your existing day array. Following code snippet may help you.

```
dataExcel = [];
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... , 31];

for(let i = 0 ; i <32; i++){
  this.dataExcel.push({
    Day: this.days[i]
  });
}
```

If the variables are defined inside the method

```
dataExcel = [];
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... , 31];

for(let i = 0 ; i <32; i++){
 dataExcel.push({
    Day:days[i]
  });
}
```

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: where did you define the `dataExcel`. If it is inside the method then you should remove the this keyword